# Using Oracle as datastore/db with webDAV instead of file system

Tags: content-management-system, webdav, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

Here is a need for fetching files (word/blob) directly from oracle and show it on browser on edit mode for editing and save it directly on oracle. Using file system is not an option due to security reasons. Please let me know if anyone has done similar earlier. Or if any idea how this can be done.

Can we use jackRabbit and WebDav for this. Using webDAV I am able to open the word file in word from file system: 
ms-word:ofe|u|http://url/webdav/Test.docx

But this is opening in word, the need is-
1) Should be able to load directly from oracle database and open in url.
2) Edit it/update it
3) Save it, while save it should directly go to oracle DB.

Can we make any code change in webDAV servlet or any class/api to use oracle to load and save directly.

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If it works from the filesystem for you, so will it with Oracle. You just need to figure the appropriate persistence manager (see https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ).

(Persistence Manager FAQ has been archived, see 
http://jackrabbit.apache.org/archive/wiki/JCR/PersistenceManagerFAQ_115513487.html
or https://web.archive.org/web/20181226012431/https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ)